# Quilljs editor set content with html attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text-editor

I am searching for a way to set default starting content in my Quilljs editor. I am using React but I think the question is more directly related to Quilljs then using it in combination with React.

I am trying to add content with some highlighted parts to be changed by the user such as the code below.

`content text with a <span class="highlighted">[variable]</span>`

The problem is, when I digging down in the output of the Quilljs editor, it has been stripped away and all lines are wrapped in `<p>` elements.

Hopefully someone has the answer for me.

Thanks